# Symfony 6 Maker Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, shopware, shopware6

I'm picking up on Shopware 6.
Is it possible to use the Maker bundle shopware?
I already did the composer require symfony/maker-bundle but it gives me problems:

> Using version ^1.43 for symfony/maker-bundle
> ./composer.json has been updated
> Running composer update symfony/maker-bundle
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
> - symfony/maker-bundle v1.43.0 requires doctrine/inflector ^2.0 -> found doctrine/inflector[2.0.0, ..., 2.1.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 1.4.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
> - symfony/maker-bundle[v1.44.0, ..., v1.45.0] require php >=8.0 -> your php version (7.4.3; overridden via config.platform, actual: 8.1.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Root composer.json requires symfony/maker-bundle ^1.43 -> satisfiable by symfony/maker-bundle[v1.43.0, v1.44.0, v1.45.0].

> Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require symfony/maker-bundle:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require symfony/maker-bundle:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Im using Shopware 6.4

> ---
>
> Symfony
>
> ---
>
> Version              5.4.11
> Long-Term Support    Yes
> End of maintenance   11/2024 (in +851 days)
> End of life          11/2025 (in +1216 days)
>
> ---
>
> Kernel
>
> ---
>
> Type                 Shopware\Core\Kernel
> Environment          dev
> Debug                true
> Charset              UTF-8
> Cache directory      ./var/cache/dev_hc61c72400ff2b806750ba16ed9d16e58 (14.9 MiB)
> Build directory      ./var/cache/dev_hc61c72400ff2b806750ba16ed9d16e58 (14.9 MiB)
> Log directory        ./var/log (101 KiB)
>
> ---
>
> PHP
>
> ---
>
> Version              8.1.3
> Architecture         64 bits
> Intl locale          en_US_POSIX
> Timezone             UTC (2022-08-02T11:40:43+00:00)
> OPcache              true
> APCu                 false
> Xdebug               false

---

Comment: it seems there is sth wrong with your php config require php >=8.0 -> your php version (7.4.3; overridden via config.platform, actual: 8.1.3) does not satisfy that requirement

Comment: Currently there is no `official support` inside shopware for the `maker bundle`. But there are already plans to use the maker bundle and extend it with shopware specific commands.

Answer (score 0):

this is more of a comment than an answer but I cant comment for some reason.
my friend had a very similar issue and it turns out in his case the problem was that the APP_ENV variable in .env file was set to prod.
so make sure in the .env file that u have APP_ENV=dev.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the composer error indicates you require a version of `symfony/maker-bundle` that requires php 8, but by default shopware is configured with php `7.4.3` as a [platform config](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform), because that is the minimal supported shopware version. This ensures that only packages are installed that are also compatible with that php version.

If you know that in your project shopware will always be running with php 8, you can remove the php platform config from the composer.json, or better set it to a project specific value.

If you also want to support all php version that shopware currently supports, you can try requiring an older version of the maker bundle, that is still compatible with php 7.4.